# Processing of the files with numerical parts

Tags: bash

In the working directory I have 7 files of the following name:

```
_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.0
_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.1
_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.2
..
_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.6
```

The following command executed from bash could load all the files at once:

```
# load all nectdf files
vmd -netcdf _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.*
```

how could I load at once all the nc files of e.g. the given range or ignore some specific file?

```
vmd -netcdf _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.{2 .. 6}
```

thus ignoring `vmd -netcdf _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.0` and `vmd -netcdf _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it. Don't put in spaces:

```
vmd -netcdf _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.{2..6}
```

Comment: Thank you ! is it possibile via the same simple syntax to ignore a specific file (e.g. to load all files but not the _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.1 ?

Comment: Not with the same syntax. This syntax simply iterates over some values without checking for the existence of files. "all files but not", however, requires checking them (or at least finding "all files" first). I'd rather go with a loop, something like `for f in _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.*; do … [ -e "$f" ] …; done`

Comment: okay if I define start_part='2' and stop_part='6' as variables would it work like  _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.{"$start_part".."$stop_part"}     ? Would you please update your answer for such case :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use variables with the `{..}` syntax. Agein, use a loop: `for i in $(seq $start_part $stop_part); do … _MMPBSA_receptor.nc.$i …; done`

Comment: Don't pile on additional requirements; (accept this answer and) ask a new question if you didn't ask what you wanted to ask.

Comment: *Unfortunately, you cannot use variables with the {..} syntax* -- Not true. The variables just need to be outside of double quotes but the [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) does support variables. See my answer for examples.

Comment: @dawg My Bash (using `GNU bash, Version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`) responds to `i=3; j=6; printf "%s\n" "File."{$i..$j}` with `File.{3..6}` (regardless of the existence of such files).

Comment: @pmf: Doh! On `zsh` it works. On *Bash* it only works for globs -- not brace expansions (since the order of expansions is different). `File.[$i-$j]` **does** work since file expansions are performed *after* parameter expansions on Bash. On `zsh` parameter expansions are *first*.

Comment: @dawg But the question is tagged with `bash`, not `zsh`. It is true, you can use `File.[$i-$j]` in Bash, but this is limited to single digits.

Answer (score 1):

or something like this and as you see you can search for files matching the pattern `_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.*` in the current directory (`.`) and then excludes files with numbers 0 and 1 using the `-not -name`!

```
vmd -netcdf $(find . -name "_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.*" -not -name "_MMPBSA_receptor.nc.[01]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
% ls -1 File*
File.0
File.1
File.2
File.3
File.5
File.6
File.7
File.8
File.9
```

(Note no `File.4`...)

And:

```
% echo "i=$i, j=$j"
i=3, j=6
```

You can use a [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to generate the text of some sequence:

```
% printf "%s\n" "File."{4..7}
File.4
File.5
File.6
File.7
```

Brace expansions **do not** supports variables (more formally, a `$` sigil introduces a [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)). (They are supported on `zsh` but not Bash...)

Since brace expansion is strictly a textual expansion, some action will fail if the file name is not found:

```
% ls -1 "File."{3..6}
ls: File.4: No such file or directory
File.3
File.5
File.6
```

You can also use a [Filename Expasion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) (glob) of a single digit, and only matching *files* are returned. This is not a textual expansion:

```
% ls -1 File.[2-5]  
File.2
File.3
File.5
```

And globs *can* use variables (outside of double quotes):

```
% ls -1 File.[$i-$j]
File.3
File.5
File.6
```